# How to check for n consecutive same characters in row in c

Tags: c, nested-loops

So my assignment is to write a program for Connect-N, which is basically the game Connect-4 but where the user specifies the number of rows and columns (doesn't have to be square) and specifies the number of consecutive pieces to win (this doesn't have to fit on the board). For example, if the user specifies a 3x3 board, they can also say 4 consecutive pieces are needed to win.

I'm having trouble writing a program to check for a row win, where the player wins the game completely horizontally. Here's what I have so far:

```
bool horizontalWin(char **board, const int numRows, 
const int numCols, const char blankSpace, const int numToWin) {
  if((numCols - numToWin) < 0) {
      return false;
  }
  else {
    for (int row = 0; row < numRows; ++row) {
      for (int col = 0; col <= numCols-numToWin; ++col) {
        ///This is where I need help
      }
    }
  }
return false;
}
```

Just for reference: the variable blankSpace is a '*' and is used to denote a blank space on the board.

My idea was to have a nested for loop that started at column 0 and then checked far enough forward to see if they were all identical characters, but I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: "if the user specifies a 3x3 board, they can also say 4 consecutive pieces are needed to win." ??? Did you mean 3 consecutive pieces?

Comment: Start at `board[0][0]` and look right, right-up, up,right down for N same color pieces.  Then `board[1][0]`, `board[2][0]`, , ... `board[numCols-1][0]`, then next row up until row `numRows-1`.

Comment: Writing `if((numCols - numToWin) < 0)` is a funny way of writing `if (numCols < numToWin)`; it harks back to Fortran II where that was the way that such tests had to be written.

Comment: Don't you have two players, so you need to check whether one of the two players has N-in-a-row, so really you don't need to know about blanks; you just need to know which player you're looking for (a value that will be different from both blank and the other player).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the number of matches, or reset the count when there is no match.

Assuming `board[row][col]`, and that the color you check is `user1`

```
for (int row = 0; row < numRows; ++row) {
    int match = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col <= numCols-numToWin; ++col) {
        if (board[row][col] != user1) match = 0;
        else {
            match++;
            if (match >= numToWin) return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you could do `if (++match >= numToWin) return true;` to save a line (if you feel this being readable).

This is not in the problem description, but if you have two players, there should be 3 colors, say `blankSpace`, `user1`, and `user2`. The program above checks if `user1` wins.

So you could add an argument to the function to tell which color you are testing for a win (say `colorCheck`), the whole function becomes

```
bool horizontalWin(char **board, const int numRows, 
const int numCols, const char blankSpace, const int numToWin, const in colorCheck) {
  if((numCols - numToWin) < 0) {
      return false;
  }
  else {
     for (int row = 0; row < numRows; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col <= numCols-numToWin; ++col) {
           if (board[row][col] != colorCheck) match = 0;
           else {
              match++;
              if (match >= numToWin) return true;
           }
        }
     }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set two counters, one for the red discs and the other for the yellow ones. Then inside the body of your nested loop whenever you encounter an `r` increment the red discs counter by one, the same goes for yellow disks.

Then you can check after each row iteration if any of these counters equals the given `N` required to win the game.

You can do it this way supposing you denote a red disk with an `r` and a yellow disk with a `y` :

```
else 
{
    int red_c, yellow_c;
    for (int row = 0; row < numRows; ++row) 
    {
          red_c=0; yellow_c=0;
          for (int col = 0; col < numCols; ++col) 
          {
                if(board[r][c]=='r') red_c++;
                else if (board[r][c]=='y') yellow_c++;

                if(red_c == numToWin )
                {
                    //Red wins
                }

                else if(yellow_c == numToWin )
                {
                    //Yellow wins
                }
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code will depend if you want to know if someone win in the board of if you win after an specific move.

This is a common and simple code that you can execute after each move or for every position in the board:

The idea is to move in every direction from the center (the new position of a piece) making something like a star " * " (like the star character)

```
consecutivesInHorizontal =0
consecutivesInVertical = 0
consecutivesDiagLeft =0
consecutiveDiagRight = 0

for i =1 ; i < height && i<width && i<= 4 ; i++
if(board[centerX][centerY+i] == myPieceColor)
    consecutivesInVertical++;
if(board[centerX][centerY-i] == myPieceColor)
    consecutivesInVertical++;

if(board[centerX+i][centerY] == myPieceColor)
    consecutivesInHorizontal++;
if(board[centerX-i][centerY] == myPieceColor)
    consecutivesInHorizontal++;

if(board[centerX+i][centerY-i] == myPieceColor)
    consecutivesDiagLeft++;
if(board[centerX-i][centerY+i] == myPieceColor)
    consecutivesDiagLeft++;

if(board[centerX-i][centerY+i] == myPieceColor)
    consecutiveDiagRight++;
if(board[centerX+i][centerY-i] == myPieceColor)
    consecutiveDiagRight

if any of the consecutive variables == 4
    return true
```